# No sound on classic headphone but mic works Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: sound, 14.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I am using a Dell Vostro 1014 running with Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit. Internal speaker front left alone is working. When I plug classic headset no sound but microphone in the headset is working.

Below is the `aplay -l` output

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`alsamixer` does not detect headphone

Ubuntu Sound setting shows Analog output and input (built in audio)

Kindly suggest how to troubleshoot.

Thank you,
Sajith

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your problem, but my headphones stopped working all of a sudden, and the solution was to do the following two things:

1. Reset user configuration (as described in the Troubleshooting section of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio);
2. Make sure **Independent HP** is **Disabled** in `alsamixer`. To do that, just type `alsamixer` in a terminal, then choose your sound card (by pressing **F6**) and move to the **Independent HP** column.

Hope it helps!